# raspberry pi epiphany html5 features

Tags: html, raspberry-pi, epiphany

i notice that epiphany is the native webbrowser for raspberry pi.
The doc mention that epiphany has a better support of html5.
But i can not find anywhere all html5 features supported by epiphany.
Especialy websocket support.
It seams that a new release is planed for march 2015. But no documentation for html5 support.
I know that epiphany is build on a webkit gtk module, but this way too lacks of documentation.

could anyone tell me where could i find documentation for all html5 features supported in epiphany ?
(Especially websocket)

Thank you

Comment: If you own a raspberry pi, you could give https://html5test.com a try. Or a member of SO with a running epiphany.

Comment: Great Idea ! i actualy don't have a raspberry i just order mine: could someone that own a raspberry pi publish the repport please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Raspberry pi 2 B with noobs, epiphany browser July 2015


HTML5TEST   
how well does your browser support html5?

YOUR BROWSER SCORES 344 OUT OF 555 POINTS

semantics
Parsing rules    5
<!DOCTYPE html> triggers standards mode   Yes ✔  
HTML5 tokenizer   Yes ✔  
HTML5 tree building   Yes ✔  

HTML5 defines rules for embedding SVG and MathML inside a regular HTML document. The following tests only check if the browser is following the HTML5 parsing rules for inline SVG and MathML, not if the browser can actually understand and render it.

Parsing inline SVG   Yes ✔  
Parsing inline MathML   Yes ✔  
Elements   24/30   
Embedding custom non-visible data    Yes ✔  

New or modified elements  
Section elements   Yes ✔  
Grouping content elements  Yes ✔  
Text-level semantic elements    Partial ○  
Interactive elements    Partial ○  

Global attributes or methods
hidden attribute    Yes ✔  
Dynamic markup insertion    Yes ✔  

Forms    47/75

Field types  
input type=text    Yes ✔  
input type=search    Yes ✔  
input type=tel    Yes ✔  
input type=url    Yes ✔  
input type=email    Yes ✔  
input type=date     No ✘  
input type=month    No ✘  
input type=week    No ✘
input type=time    No ✘
input type=datetime    No ✘
input type=datetime-local    No ✘
input type=number    Yes ✔
input type=range    Yes ✔
input type=color    No ✘
input type=checkbox    Yes ✔
input type=image    Yes ✔
input type=file    Yes ✔
textarea    Yes ✔
select    Yes ✔
fieldset    Yes ✔
datalist    No ✘
keygen    Yes ✔
output    Yes ✔
progress    Yes ✔
meter    Yes ✔

Fields    
Field validation    Yes ✔    
Association of controls and forms    Yes ✔  
Other attributes    Yes ✔  
CSS selectors    Yes ✔  
Events    Yes ✔  

Forms     
Form validation    Yes ✔  
Microdata    0  
Microdata    No ✘   

device access    
Location and Orientation    15/20  
Geolocation    Yes ✔  
Device Orientation    No ✘  
Device Motion    No ✘  

Output    5/10  
Full screen support    Prefixed ✔  
Web Notifications    No ✘  

Input     0/25  
Access the webcam    No ✘  
Gamepad control    No ✘  
Pointer Events    No ✘  
Pointer Lock support    No ✘  

connectivity    
Communication    33/35   
Server-Sent Events    Yes ✔  
Beacon    No ✘   

XMLHttpRequest Level 2  
Upload files   Yes ✔  
Response type support    Yes ✔  

WebSocket  
Basic socket communication   Yes ✔  
ArrayBuffer and Blob support    Yes ✔  
Peer To Peer    0/20  
WebRTC 1.0    No ✘  
ObjectRTC API for WebRTC    No ✘  
Data channel    No ✘    

performance & integration    

User interaction    13/20  

Drag and drop   
Attributes    Yes ✔  
Events    Yes ✔  

HTML editing  
Editing elements    Yes ✔  
Editing documents    Yes ✔  
CSS selectors    No ✘  
APIs    Yes ✔    

Clipboard    
Clipboard API and events    No ✘  

Spellcheck    
spellcheck attribute    Yes ✔  
Performance    25  
Native binary data    Yes ✔  

Workers    
Web Workers    Yes ✔
Shared Workers    Yes ✔

Security    33/40  
Web Cryptography API    No ✘  
Content Security Policy 1.0    Yes ✔  
Content Security Policy 1.1    No ✘  
Cross-Origin Resource Sharing    Yes ✔  
Cross-document messaging    Yes ✔  

Iframes    
Sandboxed iframe     Yes ✔  
Seamless iframe    Yes ✔  
iframe with inline contents    Yes ✔  

History and navigation    10  
Session history    Yes ✔  

multimedia     
Video    21/35  
video element    Yes ✔  
Subtitles    No ✘  
Audio track selection    No ✘  
Video track selection    No ✘  
Poster images    Yes ✔  
Codec detection    Yes ✔  

Advanced    
DRM support    No ✘  
Media Source extensions    No ✘  

Codecs  
MPEG-4 ASP support    Yes ✔  
H.264 support    Yes ✔  
Ogg Theora support    Yes ✔  
WebM with VP8 support    Yes ✔  
WebM with VP9 support    Yes ✔  

Audio    25/30  
audio element Yes ✔  
Loop audio    Yes ✔  
Preload in the background    Yes ✔  
Advanced  
Web Audio API    Prefixed ✔  
Speech Recognition    No ✘  
Speech Synthesis    No ✘  
Codecs  
PCM audio support    Yes ✔  
AAC support    Yes ✔  
MP3 support    Yes ✔  
Ogg Vorbis support    Yes ✔  
Ogg Opus support    Yes ✔  
WebM with Vorbis support    Yes ✔  
WebM with Opus support    Yes ✔  

3d, graphics & effects      
Responsive images    5/15  
picture element    No ✘  
srcset attribute    Yes ✔  
sizes attribute    No ✘  

2D Graphics    19/25  
Canvas 2D graphics   Yes ✔
Drawing primitives   
Text support    Yes ✔  
Path support    No ✘  
Ellipse support    No ✘  
Dashed line support    Yes ✔  
System focus ring support    No ✘  
Features    
Hit testing support    No ✘  
Blending modes    Yes ✔  
Image export formats    
PNG support    Yes ✔  
JPEG support    Yes ✔  
JPEG-XR support    No ✘  
WebP support    No ✘  
3D Graphics    0/20  
WebGL 3D graphics    No ✘  
Animation    5   
window.requestAnimationFrame    Yes ✔  

offline & storage    
Web applications    10/25  
Offline resources
Application Cache    Yes ✔  
Service Workers    No ✘  
Content and Scheme handlers    
Custom scheme handlers    No ✘  
Custom content handlers    No ✘  
Custom search providers    No ✘  
Storage    15/35  
Key-value storage    
Session Storage    Yes ✔  
Local Storage    Yes ✔  
Database storage    
IndexedDB     No ✘  
Objectstore Blob support    No ✘    
Objectstore ArrayBuffer support    No ✘  

The Web SQL Database specification is no longer being updated and has been replaced by IndexedDB. Because at least 3 vendors have shipped implementations of this specification we still include it in this test.

Web SQL Database    Yes ✔  

Files    15  
Reading files    
Basic support for reading files    Yes ✔  
Create a Blob from a file    Yes ✔  
Create a Data URL from a Blob    Yes ✔  
Create an ArrayBuffer from a Blob    Yes ✔  
Create a Blob URL from a Blob    Yes ✔  
Accessing the file system    
FileSystem API    No ✘  

The Directories and System API proposal has failed to gain traction among browser vendors and is only supported in some Webkit based browsers. No additional points are awarded for supporting this API.

File API: Directories and System    No ✘  
Streams    0/5  
Readable streams    No ✘  
Writable streams    No ✘   
other    
Web Components    2/10  
Custom elements    No ✘  
Shadow DOM    No ✘  
HTML templates    Yes ✔  
HTML imports    No ✘  
Other    17/20    
Styling    
Scoped style element    No ✘  
Scripts    
Asynchronous script execution    Yes ✔  
Runtime script error reporting    Yes ✔  
Script execution events    No ✘  
Base64 encoding and decoding    Yes ✔  
JSON encoding and decoding    Yes ✔  
URL API    Yes ✔  
Mutation Observer    Yes ✔  
Promises    Yes ✔  
Other   
Page Visibility    Yes ✔  
Text selection    Yes ✔  
Scroll into view    Yes ✔
```